# cant convert symbol to integer using select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

could anyone please tell me what is wrong this this code?

I get a **can't convert Symbol into Integer**
Extracted source (around line #5):

```
3: <% form_for @song_request do |f| %>
4: <p>Please select the event you are attending:</p>
5: <%= select_tag('song_requests', 'event_id', Event.all.collect {|e| [e.name, e.id ] } ) %>
6: <% end %>
```

Comment: Did you definitely mean 'select_tag' not just 'select'? The documentation I have suggests that select_tag expects a string containing options tags, rather than a collection of options. select() on the other hand looks to do what you want. Come back if you're still having trouble!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I agree with idlefingers that you have to go with collection_select method here (although it must read `<%= f.collection_select :event_id, Event.all, :name, :id %>`) but you also have the alternative to go with the select method as

```
<%= f.select :event_id, options_for_select(Event.all.collect{|e| [e.name,e.id]})
```

You have to note that it is a best practice to not use *_tag methods when you wrapping the form fields in a `form_for` block. That is the whole point of using `form_for` you are carrying the object `@song_request` in the iterator :)

Answer (score 2):

`collection_select` will do what you're wanting and reads much better:

```
<%= f.collection_select :event_id, Event.all, :id, :name %>
```

Comment: Thanks this was great, I had to swap name and id round